# How can I make two arrays of even and odd numbers from one array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a program that takes some numbers as input and then put even and odd numbers in two separate arrays and displays them in the form of array. I need help about how I can make this program much more better by skipping the even numbers in odd array(as I'm putting 0 instead).

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i; // n is the size of array and i is for loop
    printf("Enter the size of array here:");
    scanf("%d" ,&n);

    int num[n], even[n], odd[n]; // num will hold all numbers, even will hold even numbers and odd will hold odd numbers

    printf("\nPlease enter integers only!!!");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the number %d here:", i+1); //filling array
        scanf("%d" ,&num[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) // filling even and odd arrays
    {
        if((num[i]%2) == 0)
            even[i] = num[i];
        else
            even[i] = 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) // filling even and odd arrays
    {
        if((num[i]%2) != 0)
            odd[i] = num[i];
        else
            odd[i]= 0;
    }
    printf("\nEVEN\t\tODD\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\t\t%d\n" , even[i], odd[i]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. We see your code; it is good that you included it.  However, we don't see your question — an explanation of what you are trying to, what your code does instead, and generally what the problem is.  That is a key part of asking a question.  Some sample input data and the corresponding expected output data would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int n, i, even_index=0, odd_index=0; // n is the size of array and i is for loop
   printf("Enter the size of array here:");
   scanf("%d" ,&n);

   int num[n], even[n], odd[n]; // num will hold all numbers, even will hold even numbers and odd will hold odd numbers

   printf("\nPlease enter integers only!!!");

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       printf("\nEnter the number %d here:", i+1); //filling array
       scanf("%d" ,&num[i]);
   }

   for(i=0;i<n;i++) // filling even and odd arrays
   {
       if((num[i]%2) == 0)
       {
        even[even_index++] = num[i];
       }
       else
       {
        odd[odd_index++] = num[i];
       }
   }

   printf("\nEVEN\n");

   for(i=0;i<even_index;i++)
       printf("%d\n" , even[i]);

   printf("ODD\n");
   for(i=0;i<odd_index;i++)
       printf("%d\n" , odd[i]);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Just have two separate indices for even and odd arrays. whenever you enter an element to the array increment the respective counter.

Answer (score 0):

First, have two index variable for the even and odd array starting at 0. Then, as you loop through the big array, when you find an even or odd number, put it in its corresponding index variable location of the array. Then you increment it. This way you know exactly where to keep the even and odd variables in their respective arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use two for loop here, You can assign odd value inside else block of for loop:
Modify your code as:

```
   int conter1 = 0;
   int counter2 = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) // filling even and odd arrays
    {
        if((num[i]%2)  == 0)

            even[counter1] = num[i];
             counter1++;
        else{
            odd[counter2] = num[i];
            counter2++;
        }
    }

for(i=0;i<counter1;i++)
    printf("%d\t\n" , even[i];

 for(i=0;i<counter2;i++)
    printf("%d\t\n" , odd[i]);
```

Comment: If you have an array like [1, 3, 4] won't the two resulting arrays be [1,3] and [0, 0, 4] since you are adding num[i] at the i location in the array?

Comment: I tried it but it shows absurd output numbers.

Comment: This is not the right solution since the you are incorrectly inserting values in the wrong location in the array. Look at my approach.

Comment: @user3742303 I have edited previous answer. Please review it,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to keep two additional counts: one for even numbers, and one for odd numbers.

For example, here's an implementation with minimal changes to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i; 
    printf("Enter the size of array here: ");
    scanf("%d" ,&n);

    int num[n];
    int even[n];
    int odd[n];

    int evenCount = 0;
    int oddCount = 0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("Enter the number %d here: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d" ,&num[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if((num[i]%2) == 0)
            even[evenCount++] = num[i];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if((num[i]%2) != 0)
            odd[oddCount++] = num[i];

    for(i=0;i<evenCount;i++)
        printf("Even: %d\n", even[i]);

    for(i=0;i<oddCount;i++)
        printf("Odd: %d\n", odd[i]);
}
```

#### Output

```
Enter the size of array here: 4
Enter the number 1 here: 1
Enter the number 2 here: 2
Enter the number 3 here: 3
Enter the number 4 here: 4
Even: 2
Even: 4
Odd: 1
Odd: 3
```

Comment: Yeah...! But how to fill the arrays then?

Comment: I've included an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 indexes, one for each array. You can change the loop this way (assuming that your problem is only filling the array):

```
i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if((num[i]%2) == 0){
        even[j] = num[i];
        j++;
    }
    else{
        odd[k] = num[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```